# Progressive Web app in angular shows offline on refresh in ipad chrome browser

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

The progressive web application which was created by angular works fine in pc browsers. but in device like ipad it doesn't persist during reload of the page after make the device in offline. i mean when i click on the browser refresh button the page is not persisting .does anybody knows the reason for this?

Comment: only tested using IOS devices is the behavior different on the android devices?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.